# How to write widget test for this widget

Tags: flutter, dart, mobile, flutter-dependencies, flutter-test

My Widget of which i want to write widget test

```
InkWell(
      key: const Key(kDraftTileKey),
      onTap: () {
        context.read<CreatorHubTapViewModel>().startPublishingFlowAgain(startPublishingFlowAgainPressed: startPublishingFlowAgainPressed);
      },
      child:...
    );
```

Fucntion which called when user click on a tap

```
 void startPublishingFlowAgainPressed() {
    widget.viewModel.saveNFT(nft: widget.nft);
    Navigator.of(context).pushNamed(RouteUtil.kRouteHome);
  }
```

I create a Mock of this viewmodel using Mockito

```
class CreatorHubTapViewModel extends ChangeNotifier {
  void onViewOnPylons({required VoidCallback onViewOnPylonsPressed}) {
    onViewOnPylonsPressed.call();
  }

  void startPublishingFlowAgain({required VoidCallback startPublishingFlowAgainPressed}) {
    startPublishingFlowAgainPressed.call();
  }
}
```

Now in test when i try to make a stub on this function it is not calling `thenAnswer` also not calling `Callback` itself. Any way to achieve i just want to toggle my variable when this function calls in actual screen.

```
  when(viewModel.startPublishingFlowAgain(startPublishingFlowAgainPressed: () {
    clicked = true;
  })).thenAnswer((realInvocation) {});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how you can test this function.

```
 when(viewModel.startPublishingFlowAgain(startPublishingFlowAgainPressed: anyNamed("startPublishingFlowAgainPressed"))).thenAnswer((realInvocation) {
        clicked = true;
      });
```